# Expected value of unbiased estimator of $\sigma$ in binomial sum

Tags: maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution, expected-value

Suppose that $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_r$ are random independent variable such as $Y_i \sim B(m_i, \pi)$, the idea first is to find $\hat{\pi}$ which is the maximum likelihood estimator an use it to find the expected value of $s^2$ where:

$$
 s^2 = \frac{1}{r-1}\sum_{i=1}^{r} \frac{\left( Y_i - m_i \hat{\pi} \right)^2}{m_i \hat{\pi} \left(1 - \hat{\pi} \right)}
$$

Finding the MLE estimator is quite simple and the result is

$$
\hat{\pi} = \frac{Y_{\bullet}}{m_{\bullet}}
$$

Where $Y_{\bullet} = \sum_{i} Y_i$ and $m_{\bullet} = \sum_{i} m_i$. The final answer is:

$$
E\left[ s^2 \right] = \frac{m_{\bullet}}{m_{\bullet} - 1}
$$

But even though I have tried to modify the expresion of $s^2$ in different ways, I still cannot find one that fits the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There must be a typographical error in your first formula, because it is undefined when $r=1$ and otherwise is *negative.*

Comment: Thanks, indeed there was an error.

Comment: It still looks suspicious. The reason is that there is a nonzero chance that for every $i,$ $Y_i=m_i,$ in which case $s^2$ is undefined: so how can it have an expectation at all? Perhaps the intention is to set $s^2=0$ in this case, but evidently that's something you will have to pay attention to during any algebraic manipulations.

Comment: Hey @whuber That's a really interesting observation, I have followed the formulation from the book I took exercise from. Definitely, this is something that has to be taken into account in the manipulations.